# How should I build a website for someone else who wants to embed their own Youtube links?

Tags: php, html, sql, database, video-embedding

first post here.

I am making a site for someone who wants to embed their own youtube links. I am relatively new to web development and this is my first commission so I was wondering how I could hand over the site to the client and allow them to upload their links without me having to edit the mark up for him.

I understand how to use an '<iframe' youtube link in HTML to embed videos and am considering creating a database using PHPmyadmin that uses a form that the client can fill in with the iframe link whenever he needs to embed a new video.

I understand if that sounds like a convoluted way of doing this but if anyone knows a more intuitive way to solve this issue please let me know :)

Comment: I would go for something like : client copy paste youtube url and then you in back end you create the iframe. You'll find some tutorials on that in the internet. You need a specific structure to embed youtube video, you just have to get the code of the video then use it to embed the video properly.

Comment: *"... and am considering creating a database ..."* - That is indeed the generally common approach to allowing a user to edit content without having to directly edit the page markup.  Sounds like you're off to the right start, at least in an extremely broad sense.  (Too broad to really be meaningfully answered here, honestly.)

Comment: It might make sense to consider a _let's not reinvent the wheel_ sort of approach. Why don't you try to find a CMS that could  allow you to build sites / apps for your clients where you can focus on the higher level 'design' of the system, while leaving the nuts and bolts of e.g. editing (existing) HTML pages, and database transactions to the CMS? There are many open source CMSs, more or less sophisticated, surely one will fit your needs.

Comment: To be honest the best approach would probably be a Wordpress page. Your question sounds a bit like you have to get the basics right first. Everyone has to start, but building something like this from scratch might be a bit much.

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be done using a database, may be MySQL, to keep it simple and a simple backend programming language, PHP would do.

1. You create an admin page just to collect the URLs from the admin. A nice little login page which stores admin username and password in a table. And you can use this module to assign roles to admin, add an admin or delete one.
2. Inside the module created above, create a page with a form to fetch and store URLs in the database. If you are going to categorize the videos, use suitable columns. Say you are going to categorize based on the genre and length, the table in your database should contain genre and length so that you can use them as filters later on.
3. Use cookies to create session for the admin. This is to avoid redirecting him to the login page after every single reload.
4. For all other user who is not admin, do not redirect to the admin page. Redirect them to a common page where they can search and enjoy the videos that the admin has added.

Again, like mentioned in many comments above, wordpress does it all. You have an option to use it too, it's free.